# Use the default copy constructor [Java]

Tags: java

Having the following:

```
public interface IntA{ }

public class A implements IntA{}

public class A2 extends A {

 public A2(IntA a) {
  if(a instanceof A)
     this(a);
  else
    // whatever

 }
}
```

I want in case `a` is instance of `A` then I want that `this` reference A and not creates a deep copy of it, otherwise `this` becomes a new object (new reference). Is this possible?

Comment: No, use a factory method or do that in your client code.

Comment: java does not have a default copy constructor. That being said, I question your design.

Comment: Make two constructors. One that takes an argument of type ``A`` and a default one. Java does not allow code before a call to a different constructor inside another constructor.

Comment: Well is an oversimplification. The real problem is actually multi-inheritance, that is not possible in java. The source of the problem is that I have two instances of different classes which should be the same. I'm searching a solution that makes to the problem as transparent as possible to user of my class.

Comment: So it's an XY problem then? Can you show a usage scenario?

Comment: @ender.an27 Can you provide a more representative example, then, before anybody else spends time constructing an answer for you?

Comment: @JornVernee I'm not sure. I would have to think of another way to express it, without pasting lot of unnecessary code. Also, I think then will be another question.

Comment: @ender.an27 What does "two instances of different classes which should be the same" mean?

Comment: @JasonC ok, but probably will not be today anymore (just warning).

Comment: @ender.an27 I wasn't planning on losing sleep over it, but thanks for the warning, lol... :P

Comment: @JasonC means that there are two classes made out of my control. I want to create one that give the less effort. I know this is an adapter pattern. I was searching alternatives that cost me lot less code.

Comment: @ender.an27 Do these two classes have enough in common that you can essentially boil them down to the same interface? Also is it a requirement that your "combined" class has one or both of the original ones as a base?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122264/discussion-between-ender-an27-and-jason-c).